# Enable syntax highlighting for CUDA 7.0 in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, cuda

**Direct Question**: Is it possible to enable syntax highlighting for CUDA 7.0 in Visual Studio 2013, and if so, how does one do it?

**Background**:
I tried to follow [this](http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2010/10/visual-studio-2010-adding-intellisense-support-for-cuda-c/) guide, but can't find a `usertype.dat` file (does it still ship with this version?). I didn't find the file at the locations mentioned in [1](http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2010/10/visual-studio-2010-adding-intellisense-support-for-cuda-c/), [2](http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2010/10/visual-studio-2010-adding-intellisense-support-for-cuda-c/), [3](http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2010/10/visual-studio-2010-adding-intellisense-support-for-cuda-c/).

Answer (score 8):

Try The following Steps

To set syntax highlighting support for your Visual Studio CUDA Project, make the following steps:

---

> • Go to:  Tools -> Options -> Project and Solutions -> VC++ Project
>   Settings -> Extensions to Include -> add “.cu” (and “.cuh” if you
>   like);
>
> ---
>
> • Go to:  Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> VC++
>   Directories -> Include Directories -> add $(CUDA_INC_PATH)
>
> • Go to:   Tools –> Options -> Text Editor -> File Extension -> add
>   “cu” to Extension, select Microsoft Visual C++ as Editor and then OK

---

> • Copy usertype.dat from C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA
>   Samples\v5.0\doc\syntax_highlighting\visual_studio_8 to C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE

---

The first step will make Visual Studio 2010 know that cu should be dealt with in a similar way as cpp file.

The second step will enable right click on a CUDA header file and select Open Document.

The third step will enable standard keyword coloring on .cu files.

The fourth step will extend the coloring to CUDA keywords.

Comment: The last step is still the problem. I've this directory C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v7.0 but no doc folder.

Comment: It seems the last step is in fact not necessary anymore. __ device __ and other specific keywords are already colored. I included #include "cuda_runtime.h" and #include "device_launch_parameters.h" and now everything is highlighted except the <<< >>> calls, but that's a known problem.

Comment: I have the doc folder in c:ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v8.0\doc\  but no usertype.dat to colorize in it.